# CSV to dictionary having headers as keys and the rest of rows as lists of strings (values) in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV like this:

```
(row 0)    key1   key2   key3
(row 1)    A      D      G
(row 2)    B      E      H
(row 3)    C             I
```

I want to read it and get the information into a dictionary as follows:  `dict = {key1: ["A", "B", "C"], key2: ["D", "E"], key3: ["G", "H", "I"]}`.

So basically I want to have the first row as keys and all the values per column as values of a list (the list is the value of the key in the dictionary).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `stack` and `groupby` aggregating the values to a `list`, and turn to a dictionary with `.to_dict()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv")
df.stack().groupby(level=1).agg(list).to_dict()
# {'key1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'key2': ['D', 'E'], 'key3': ['G', 'H', 'I']}
```

Comment: in question, `I` is in `key3` not in `key2`

Comment: Yes, that's just for how I read the string @oreopot Thanks